# Uiautomator - takeScreenshot -is there a way to take screenshots for different UI object

Tags: android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

In a uiautomator test, is there a way to take screenshots for different UI object. For example, there are two UI elements (one is view class, one is scroll View class), how can I take screen shots for these two UI elements separately?

Using takeScreenshot() only takes screen shots for the whole screen view.

Thanks!

Comment: `screenshot` is for entire screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) to take snapshots of particular Views.

Using [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) you can just just use the context menu and then *[Take View snapshot and save to file](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI#take-view-snapshot)*.

A line similar to this will be generated in the test or script

```
android___id_widget_frame.writeImageToFile('/tmp/${serialno}-android___id_widget_frame-${timestamp}.png', 'PNG')
```

which you can adapt to your needs. Then, every time you run the test or script you will have a new snapshot taken.

Comment: Can I run the test/script generated by culebra in Java program of UIAutomator?

Comment: Not yet, but very soon. The new *[Culebra Tester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/)* which is on private beta now will be released in a couple of weeks and it can generate Java code that can be directly imported in Studio.

Comment: Anything I can try with Culebra Tester for now?